# XML document in infopath Form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, web-services

I have created a custom list. There are different types of columns like single line of text, number, DateTime. I want to submit data in this list using web service from Infopath form. So I have already created XML file and configure data connection within XML Document. But I can't submit date and number in related types of column in SharePoint list.

I hear that we can create the XML file which contains all the connections by using owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={Guid}&View={Guid}&XMLDATA=TRUE. can some one tell me the steps how to create the XML file for connections? How can i write it in XML File?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded to submit data from one Infopath form into multiple (N) sharepoint lists having followed

- [Matt Faus Add SharePoint List Items with InfoPath (CAML)](http://www.infopathdev.com/blogs/matt/archive/2006/02/02/Add-SharePoint-List-Items-with-InfoPath.aspx)

  Only I created one XML file per each receive data connection  (instead of one in above article) for respectively + many sharepoint lists (instead of one in article), respectively.

Respectively, I  added N submit data connections to _http://sharepointserver/_vti_bin/lists.asmx webservice, instead one in article

I did not insert Submit button, as in the article (since it is redundant to already built-in ribbon's Submit button) having used "Submit Options":

- Perform custom action using Rules
  To set rules that will run when a user submits the form, on the Data tab, in the Rules group, click Form Submit

having added to **Form Submit** a rule  that "Run these actions:"  **Submit using a data connection** having added the above created N submit data connections to a webservice.